# On some integral involving the Liouville sum

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Define $L(x) = \sum_{n\leq x} \lambda(n)$, where $\lambda$ denotes the [Liouville function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_function). If $c$ is the supremum of the real parts of the zeros of the Riemann zeta function and $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes the integer part of $x$, is it true that 
$$\Bigl\lvert\int_{1}^{x} L(y)\lfloor x/y\rfloor\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y} \Bigr\rvert > x^{c-\epsilon}$$ for arbitrarily large $x$ and any $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: $\int_{1}^{x} L(y)\lfloor x/y\rfloor\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y} = \int_1^x \frac{\lfloor \sqrt{t}\rfloor}{2t}dt$

Comment: It does not seem to be true. If you try $x=10^4$ and $\epsilon=10^{-5}$, either directly in your inequality, ,or in the inequality obtained from the comment above, Mathematica will tell you this is not true. You have to be careful with your inequality because the integral fails to converge adequately.